# Why does SO search do a worse job than generic Google search?

Tags: discussion, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can I find a certain question without any problems using Google, but not via SO’s site search?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129360/why-can-i-find-a-certain-question-without-any-problems-using-google-but-not-via)

I searched on Google (not site-specific) for "org.gjt.mm.mysql" and this page [What is the jdbc driver "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver" for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808160/what-is-the-jdbc-driver-org-gjt-mm-mysql-driver-for) was #2 result. When I search on SO for "org.gjt.mm.mysql" that question is not even listed. This is not a complex/vague search, the exact string is in the question *title*.

What's the issue here?

Comment: "org.gjt.mm.mysql" != "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver". The SO search isn't treating periods as word boundaries.

Comment: Google = billions of dollars, hundreds of developers. Stack Exchange = not so much money, only few developers who are busy with more important things. This pretty much sums it up, think it was already said somewhere, will look for it.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Google didn't spend $billions on figuring out how to search for an exact search term on a single web page, but on how to efficiently search the entire web. That's a lazy argument.

Comment: My point is that Google can do virtually anything with the power they got, the code behind their search is result of great many hours of work of great many developers. In the specific case you brought, they split words by the "." character and smart enough to look for each of them as separate word then "merge" the results. Mimicking all those things that are trivial for Google is something that sites just can't afford to themselves.

Comment: Anyway, you can search Stack Exchange using [this custom search page](http://stackexchange.com/search), for example [this one](http://stackexchange.com/search?q=org.gjt.mm.mysql) brings the question you mentioned as first result so it "works". :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd awesome comment, thank you for posting that.  +1