# Search problem in Data Explorer

Tags: bug, data-explorer

When I put a simple query into Data Explorer search box it yields [nothing](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=archaeologist%20progress). The same query in google [works](https://www.google.pl/#q=archaeologist+progress&spell=1), giving the expected result at the top.

It's not tag related as in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129360/why-can-i-find-a-certain-question-without-any-problems-using-google-but-not-via) question (because wrapping the words with quotes [together](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=%22archaeologist%20progress%22), or [separately](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=%22archaeologist%22%20%22progress%22) doesn't change the result), nor it does contain dots as in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156751/why-does-so-search-do-a-worse-job-than-generic-google-search) question.

I don't think that the answer about Google's "bilions of dollars and hundreds of developers" is relevant, as "archaeologist progress" are just two simple words.

So my question is: is it a bug, or a feature? ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a feature that sucks so badly that I'm willing to call it bug-ish. The search just does a simple `LIKE '%terms%'` against the query title/descriptions, so your search fails because while those words are in the title, they are not consecutive. [Adding in the missing word](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=archaeologist+badge+progress) works, although I can't say that the results are very helpful either.

The reality is that search on Data Explorer greatly needs to be improved to be effective, which I hope will happen sooner than later.

Comment: Any traction with this? This is search 101 stuff. I'm a bit amazed (and almost ashamed) that there isn't a text-based search engine powering search on data explorer. It would be straightforward to implement (I have done this myself at a commercial site). And I won't even (re)open the "support for regex search" issue...

Answer (score 6):

Given Tim's answer, a current workaround is to separate words with % to get them to be considered not sequentially.

I.e. [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=archaeologist%25progress) works for the moment.

Comment: Thanks, that's great! Tim's answer seems "better" though, because the question wasn't about solving the problem, but explaining it. I'd set both answers as accepted if I could, sorry. Regardless of the fact that reputation is meaningless here, I'm still feeling bad, that an up-vote is the only possibility for me to reward this answer :)

Comment: @BartoszKP That's OK I upvoted Tim's answer too. I almost made mine a comment, but it is an answer, in that it is an unintended feature :-)